# How to create an SQL query where I can select the max number of one column with an WHERE & AND clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create an SQL Query. I am stuck since I can't get the result that I want. I am using phpMyAdmin to try out these query's,

## What I have tried:

I have tried to use the GROUP BY and WHERE clause, but I can't get it to work.

## Query's I have tried:

```
SELECT products.product_name, 
    orderitem.quantity,
    products.product_price
FROM orderitem 
    INNER JOIN producten ON orderitem.FKproductID = products.productID
    INNER JOIN orders ON orderitem.FKproductID = orders.orderID
    INNER JOIN tables ON orders.FKtableID = tables.tableID
WHERE tables.tablelnr = '1'
```

and

```
SELECT products.product_name,
    orderitem.quantity,
    products.product_price,
    tables.tablenr,
    MAX(orders.ordernr)
FROM orderitem
    INNER JOIN products ON orderitem.FKproductID = producten.productID
    INNER JOIN orders ON orderitem.FKorderID = orders.orderID
    INNER JOIN tables ON orders.FKorderID = tables.tablelID
GROUP BY tables.tablenr
```

and

```
SELECT products.product_name,
    orderitem.quantity,
    products.product_price
FROM orderitem
    INNER JOIN producten ON orderitem.FKproductID = products.
    INNER JOIN orders ON orderitem.FKproductID = orders.
    INNER JOIN tables ON orders.FKtableID = tables.tableID
WHERE tables.tablelnr = '1'
AND orders.ordernr = MAX(order.ordernr)
```

For clarification this is the database and tables:

[image]
The tables content:

## Result I tried to have

So the result would be the name of the product, the quantity, the price and the table number WHERE tablenumber is equal to X AND the maximum ordernr of the table X.

Let's say there are 4 orders with 4 order numbers. Three orders belong to table 1 and one order belongs to table 2. Then I would like to get the highest order number(3) and where table number = 1.

So basically I want the highest number of a column, and also where something is equal to.

If there are any questions regarding my explanation, please ask. This is quite difficult to explain.

My table data(phpmyadmin SQL export):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 25, 2019 at 08:04 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.3.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `overflow`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `orderitem`
--

CREATE TABLE `orderitem` (
  `orderItemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FKorderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FKproductID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orderitem`
--

INSERT INTO `orderitem` (`orderItemID`, `quantity`, `FKorderID`, `FKproductID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 2, 2),
(4, 5, 3, 4),
(5, 2, 4, 1),
(6, 1, 4, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `orders`
--

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ordernr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FKtableID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders`
--

INSERT INTO `orders` (`orderID`, `ordernr`, `FKtableID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 4, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` text NOT NULL,
  `product_price` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`productID`, `product_name`, `product_price`) VALUES
(1, 'cola', '2.50'),
(2, 'pepsi', '2.50'),
(3, 'egg', '6.00'),
(4, 'cake', '10.00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tables`
--

CREATE TABLE `tables` (
  `tableID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tablenr` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tables`
--

INSERT INTO `tables` (`tableID`, `tablenr`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `orderitem`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderitem`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`orderItemID`),
  ADD KEY `FKorderID` (`FKorderID`),
  ADD KEY `FKproductID` (`FKproductID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`),
  ADD KEY `FKtableID` (`FKtableID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`productID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tables`
--
ALTER TABLE `tables`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tableID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `orderitem`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderitem`
  MODIFY `orderItemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  MODIFY `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `productID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tables`
--
ALTER TABLE `tables`
  MODIFY `tableID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `orderitem`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderitem`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orderitem_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FKorderID`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orderitem_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FKproductID`) REFERENCES `products` (`productID`);

--
-- Constraints for table `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FKtableID`) REFERENCES `panbake`.`tafels` (`tafelID`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The desired data would be like this, but then at ordernr only the highest instead of all ordernr:
https://snag.gy/kUln45.jpg

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing exampel data and expected results..

Comment: It's not complicated lol that. If you want the highest value of an colum suppose it's id and you need highest id so query would be.    "Select id from products order by id DESC Limit 1" .This will retrieve the highest record in id colum .if you want the lowest record then replace DESC with ASC .

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also, I don't see `table 1` and `table 2` in your schema.

Comment: With table 1 and 2 I mean the table with the name Table. And 1 and 2 as tablenr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you need to:

```sql
set @tablenr = 1; --You are able to change the variable value here

select Product_name, quantity, product_price, ordernr, tablenr
from (
select Product_name, quantity, product_price, ordernr, tablenr, rank() over (order by ordernr desc) rnk
FROM orderitem oi
    INNER JOIN products p ON oi.FKproductID = p.productID
    INNER JOIN orders o ON oi.FKorderID = o.orderID
    INNER JOIN tables t ON o.FKtableID = t.tableID
    where tablenr = @tablenr ) a 
    where rnk = 1
```

Here is the test result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb16483b25fc3fb800d34974369c8ce5)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I've tried out your query in my database and it does comeback with a result after a small fix. (in the 3rd INNER JOIN o.FKorderID must be o. FKtableID)

Comment: But I don't get the result I wanted. I get all the products where the tablenr is 1, but from multiple order numbers. I only wanted to receive the highest back. Thanks for your asnwer anyway, maybe you didn't understand my question.

Comment: let's say table 1 with table nr 1 has multiple orders, With your query I get all the orders the table has placed. But I wanted to receive the highest ordernr. So if tablenr 1 has placed 3 orders, I would've received all the items with ordernr 3, and where the tablenr is 1. I hope you can understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Cody Could you add some sample data and your desired result in your post? Then I can try it out.

Comment: I've added an SQL export query from phpmyadmin. I hope this is enough, if not let me know what you need more.

Comment: @Cody I added my test result. What is your desired result based on your sample data?

Comment: I've just added my desired test result underneath the sql export.

Comment: Your test result does work for tablenr 2, but What if I need tablenr 1 to show it's highest ordernr.

Comment: @Cody Do you only need tablenr = 1 ??

Comment: I would like to be able to select it myself, I am going to set the hard number 1 in this case to a variable. So I need to select multiple tablenr's.

Comment: @Cody in this question, you want the highest ordernr for each product when tablenr = 1? is that right?

Comment: @Cody I just put where tablenr = 1 and I can get your desired result. Please check the update.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But I need to be able to change tablenr =1 into tablenr = 2 for example. Thanks for all this effort by the way. Your link does not work.

Comment: @Please check the updated answer. Is that what you want? I am not sure if you are asking for PHP help?

Comment: I am so sorry I am asking so much of your time. No it's not the answer I wanted. In the row ordernr there are number 1,1,2,3. But I only wish to see the highest. Where the table number is 1, or 2 for example.

Comment: Your answer is also incorrect sorry. When I select table 2, It does indeed select the last ordernr which is correct. But only shows 1 product. But the order with ordernr 3 has multiple items. In the OrdeItems table you can see It has multiple.

Comment: @Cody You need the rank function in this case. Finally, I got what you are saying. Please see the update.

Comment: Dude you are the man, thanks a lot i've selecter your answer as the one. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an aggregate function or group-by, everything being selected in a single query will need to be an aggregate OR included in the group by. Can you break out part of your query into a sub-query and then join back to the parent?

```
SELECT products.product_name, orderitem.quantity, products.product_price
FROM Products
INNER JOIN orderitem on orderitem.FK = products.id
INNER JOIN(
     SELECT MAX(orders.ordernr), tables.tablelnr, orders.ID 
     FROM Orders
     INNER JOIN tables on orders.FK = tables.tableID
     WHERE tables.tablelnr = '1'
     GROUP BY Tables.tablelnr, orders.id) as tbl
ON products.fk = tbl.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I can follow your query untill the last two lines. Products.fk does not exist since de products table soes not have a foreign key, and I dont understand the tbl.id part. I dont know what ID to get.